# Tcpdump how counting packets in given amount of time

Tags: pcap, tcpdump

I need to count the packages on an interface after a certain filter. Let's say I want to see how many packages per second I have with Filter Syn. The command below counts these packages, but fail to find an option to see how many requests of this kind are in a given time(10 seconds let's say)

```
sudo tcpdump -vv dst host x.x.x..x and 'tcp[tcpflags] == tcp-syn'
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually another application that solves this problem very simply. It is called tcpstat. Some years ago, I used it often, but until now I had completely forgotten. https://frenchfries.net/paul/tcpstat/